# How to recover RAID 1 array from a single device during reshape?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid, software-raid

I have one disk that is in raid 4 reshaping from a previous raid 1. According to examine mode by mdadm, the disk is marked as a spare in a raid 4 array of 3 disks. I was hoping to recover data on it by as my thinking was that there should be a full copy of the data on this one disk. Is it possible and what commands must I use to mount and recover my data?
This is the output of the one disk I am attempting to recover from:

```
/dev/sdc:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x44
     Array UUID : 6da3242c:77685ea5:83fa962f:8ea9c60d
           Name : lenovo1:0  (local to host lenovo1)
  Creation Time : Sun Mar 27 13:17:54 2022
     Raid Level : raid4
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 3906699264 sectors (1862.86 GiB 2000.23 GB)
     Array Size : 3906699264 KiB (3.64 TiB 4.00 TB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
     New Offset : 263936 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : c7fd4138:36e51d1a:6c61078a:5543a13d

  Reshape pos'n : 96435328 (91.97 GiB 98.75 GB)
  Delta Devices : 1 (2->3)

    Update Time : Sat Jan 20 10:33:21 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 264 sectors
       Checksum : 20e13a01 - correct
         Events : 0

     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : spare
   Array State : A.. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

Context:
A few months ago I messed my storage system up and changed the RAID array level from 1 to 4. This triggered a reshape. I attempted to stop the change by rebooting the system as mdadm wasn't listening to manually inputted stop signals by echoing freeze, etc. into the /sys interfaces as other online resources suggested. I did a system shutdown due to the fact that I thought my mdadm was bugged and thinking that the system shutdown would gracefully end the reshape. That halted the reshape and systemd was unable to fully reboot due to the mdadm hanging process. I manually killed my system and rebooted, it attempted to continue with the reshape and in my further attempts to stop it from reshaping (it would have taken me 24h to reshape) I halted the array, upon rebuilding it would bug out and put one disk in failed and the other in spare. I couldn't mount the filesystem either and have been bugged out about this problem. I've been busy the past few months hence my post now.

Comment: You've pretty much destroyed your data. Time to restore from backup, unfortunately

Comment: That's assuming you've already tried to access the RAID 1 mirrors as filesystems, that is. If you haven't then there's a small chance you're good

Comment: @ChrisDavies yeah that was my fear too but logically speaking it should work, maybe I should ask the mdadm mailing list. When running the raid array from that one spare drive, lsblk doesn't show my EXT4 partition that was supposed to hold my data. I think that is due to the reshape. I wonder how I can continue the reshape...

Comment: There are a number of mdadm experts on Unix&Linux. If you get no joy here, ask the mods to migrate this there. Good luck